# Translating SQL Server join with COLLATE to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, join, collate

I have a SQL Server bit of code like this:

```
SELECT    [something]
FROM      [Table1] 
          JOIN [Table2] 
               ON [Table1].Field = [Table2].Field COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

How can I rewrite this to work in Oracle?

I've consulted a few places [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352095/oracle-sql-collation), but I'm a little confused about how to translate a wildcard search into a join query.

Comment: You don't need the `collate` in Oracle (but you *do* need to remove those dreaded square brackets)

Comment: Ha. I don't know why, but I included them in the question as I thought it might look neater. I would never code with them. So basically, that part is redundant in this join is what you're saying?

Comment: `COLLATE` in SQL Server is used to override the column collation where appropriate -- for example, if `[Table1].Field` is using a case-sensitive collation and you want the comparison to be case-insensitive, you'd need a `COLLATE` override. Ditto if you are dealing with a migrated table using an old collation from previous versions. Obviously, if your database is well-designed, this is fairly rare. I have no idea what Oracle does regarding collations (an earlier version of this comment foolishly linked to the MySQL docs, which is of course "also Oracle" now.)